# SQLite getReadableDatabase() returns NULL

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I'm using Android's SQLite to create a database of levels, based on some files. I first create a SQLiteOpenHelper, and on it I call getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase() so the onCreate() method is called and my DB will be created:

```
@Override //Main Activity
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbHelper = new DbOpenHelper(this);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();  //is a field
```

-

```
public DbOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d("CREATING CLASSS", "OSDIFJE*(#");
}

 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DB_TABLE_CREATE);
    loadLevelData();
}

// Load data into the database on creation
private void loadLevelData() {
    Log.d("DbOpenHelper", "Loading Level Data");
    AssetManager mgr = MenuActi ~~snip~~                                                     
    Log.d("dataaosdifj",MenuActivity.database.toString()); //NullPointerException!
    MenuActivity.database.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, info);
        }
```

i Also tried calling getWritableDatabase() inside the loadLevelData() method, same results.
I saw this is quite a common problem, however most threads about it don't have any solution!

Please :'(

Comment: Is your DbOpenHelper extending SQLiteOpenHelper? what is the type of database?

Comment: yes, and database is a SQLiteDatabase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are accessing an instance variable from an activity from inside your open helper? If I understand your code correctly, your `loadLevelData()` method is a method of your open helper. Instead of what you have, why not this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DB_TABLE_CREATE);
    loadLevelData(db);
}

// Load data into the database on creation
private void loadLevelData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    ...
    db.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, info);
}
```

The root of your problem is that the `database` instance variable in your activity isn't assigned by the time you access it down in your DbOpenHelper... you're still in the call that's creating the database -- which happens to be `dbHelper.getWritableDatabase()` -- and the result hasn't returned for the assignment.

Comment: OFCOURSE! It was basically refering to itself, within it's creation. I'll first have to fix some other things too it turned out, but this really helped.